# Parse an Object in Angular Component Template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object in my address.component.ts as follows:

```
address : any;
```

This is the data that gets populated in address from back-end

```
{street1: "abc"
 city: "some state"
 country: "some country"
}
```

I am getting this data after calling a  service.

My Template file is as follows:

```
<h1>{{address}}</h1>
```

On the browser, it is displayed as follows:

```
[Object object]
```

Instead of this I want to display entire address Object. I know I can do

```
<h1>{{address.street1}}</h1>
<h1>{{address.state}}</h1>
<h1>{{address.country}}</h1>
```

But I don't want to do it because there is a possibility that back-end might change the fields in address (like adding one more field). Is there any way I can display all the data in `address` object instead of just `[Object object]` on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<h1 ng-repeat="(key, value) in address">{{value}}</h1>
```

`ng-repeat` repeats your element based on the condition in it.

For more information please see [ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for getting all information. After it, print it in HTML:

```
var newAddress = Object.values(address);
```